# Javascript to replace styles on a table selected with id

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, inline

I'm having trouble changing table properties with Javascript (I can't edit the HTML directly).

The table has an id, and style= was used to set the background color etc.

```
<table rules="all" id="cphMain_gvStore" style="background-color:#DEBA84;border-color:#DEBA84;border-width:1px;border-style:None;border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr style="color:White;background-color:#A55129;font-weight:bold;">
            <th scope="col">StoreName</th><th scope="col">Store Functions</th>
        </tr><tr style="color:#8C4510;background-color:#FFF7E7;"
```

The colors are horrible so I want to change them. It seems like I've tried everything (innerhtml, .replace, for's and if's etc) but I just can't seem to select the table by id and change the areas I want. Any ideas?

I've successfully used Javascripts to replace other html content but this seems to be ignored.

- Can tables be chosen by id like a div?
- Is the _ a problem in the id?
- Can I change the style like an attrib?
- Is the - a problem for the Javascript?

EDITED based on comments below

Comment: If you've tried "everything", could you show us at least one example of something you tried? We're here to help you fix your code, not write it for you.

Comment: Try with `#cphMain_gvStore { background-color: blue !important ;}`

Comment: thanks. tried that. before and after the table.

Comment: I've used javascripts to replace other html content but this seems to be ignored. 

Can tables be chosen by id like a div? 

Is the _ a problem in the id? 

Can I change the style like an attrib?

Is the - a problem for the javascript?